# How to translate "pinchando"?

Tags: modismos

I was looking up a word on the Real Academia Española website. It didn't have what I was looking for, and gave a link to a Twitter feed where I could ask about the word.

In the explanation, I found this sentence, which says the feed will give more detailed explanations:

> Pinchando en la pregunta, se accede a información más detallada con enlaces que llevan a explicaciones más amplias.

I'm fine with the Spanish except for *pinchando*. Is *pinchando en la pregunta* an idiom? I don't understand how to puncture, prick, tap, prod or nick a question would offer any insight.

Incidentally, I gave that sentence to Google Translate just now, and it bonked worse than usual. According to Google, the *pinchando* phrase means "cluthing in the question." I have no idea what it's babbling about, but "cluthing" is no word I've ever heard, in English or any other language.

**Edit**: I originally gave GT the entire passage that contained the sentence (since that was easier), including a linebreak:

> Dudas rápidas
> Se resuelven aquí de forma concisa algunas de las dudas más frecuentes planteadas por los hispanohablantes. Las respuestas relacionadas con cuestiones no contempladas aún en las obras académicas son provisionales y podrían verse modificadas en el futuro. Pinchando en la pregunta, se accede a información más detallada con enlaces que llevan a explicaciones más amplias. Para encontrar la respuesta a su duda, escriba en el buscador las palabras clave de su consulta.

You can try it yourself. With the linebreak, *pinchando* is translated as "cluthing" while removing it renders the correct "clicking." Who knew Google was so fussy? Pro Tip: when you use GT in the future, stick to the part you're interested in and never include a linebreak.

Comment: Are you sure the word wasn't "clutching"? Interestingly, [GT gets it right](https://translate.google.com/?sl=es&tl=en&text=Pinchando%20en%20la%20pregunta%2C%20se%20accede%20a%20informaci%C3%B3n%20m%C3%A1s%20detallada%20con%20enlaces%20que%20llevan%20a%20explicaciones%20m%C3%A1s%20amplias.&op=translate) for me: "_By clicking on the question, more detailed information is accessed with links that lead to more extensive explanations_."

Comment: @terdon that works for me here too and is, to my eyes, correct which is a bonus.

Comment: Umm, though I'm barely able to converse in it, I grew up hearing Mexican Spanish (in Southern California), and this sounds to my ears like a form of the very rude word 'pinche'. I would love it if someone could address the question of whether this is a case of different words sounding very similar, or whether it only has this connotation in certain areas.

Comment: I have, on occasion heard an English speaker use "punching" instead of "clicking".  By punching on the question...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Pinchar* in this sentence just means "to click", see meaning 11 [on DLE](https://dle.rae.es/pinchar). The sentence means

- By **clicking** on the question, you can access more detailed information with links to more thorough explanations.

Other ways of saying "to click" are *[clicar](https://dle.rae.es/clicar#TAjMwGI)*, *[cliquear](https://dle.rae.es/cliquear?m=form)*, or *hacer [clic](https://dle.rae.es/clic)*.

Comment: with links to more thorough explanations. I upvoted and don't understand why others do not.

Comment: It would be "*cliquear*" for some of us :D

Comment: Just to add a bit more background, "pinchar" literally means "to pierce", or "to puncture", and since the mouse cursor looks like an arrowhead... you get the idea =)
Funny thing is that when you actually click on a link, the mouse cursor becomes a hand instead!

Comment: @nanaki I see from your profile that you're in Barcelona, which is where I learned Spanish. I don't think I've ever heard _pinchar_ for this, only _hacer click_, _clicar_ and _cliquear_ so I assumed that _pinchar_ was from other regional dialects. Would you use _pinchar_  yourself? And, if so, are you from Spain (or Catalunya) originally or is your idiolect from another region?

Comment: @terdon I am native from Barcelona, indeed. Actually, I have mostly *read* the term *pinchar* to refer to the action of clicking on a link, and the only rare cases where I have *heard* it, it was from not-so-young people, not much acquainted with computers, when they want to sound tech-savvy (unsuccessfully). I'd naturally use *hacer clic(k)*, and I'd say is the most common thing here along with *clicar*. Also, I'd say *cliquear* is mostly used in LATAM Spanish.

Comment: @nanaki thanks! That's my feeling as well, but since I am not a native speaker, I wanted to be sure.